# biblatex: Closing Square Bracket Causes Trouble in Bibliography / References Heading Name (title) (Chapter Name or Section Name)

Tags: biblatex

- I want to use a **custom name** for the **heading** of the **Bibliography/References**.
- Apparently a **closing square bracket `]` causes problems**.
- I use the syntax **`\printbibliography[title = ...]`**.
- Enclosing the title string with `{}` does not seem to solve the problem.
- Only `title = Test [Test{]}` seems to work.
- **Question:** Why is that and what is the best practice (intended appraoch) to solve this?

---

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{westfahl:space}.

\printbibliography[title = Test [Test]] % "{Test [Test]}" does not work. "Test [Test{]}" does work.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\printbibliography[title = {{Test [Test]}}]` works

Comment: @moewe Thanks! I try it.

Comment: @Skillmon Ahhh :). I see. **Both of you** can add an answer. Ideally with an explanation. I will upvote both and accept the first answer.

Comment: @moewe See one comment above.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner that would forcefully create a duplicate, and since I'm pretty sure @moewe knows more than me about `biblatex` I'll leave it to him.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why one needs two levels of braces here. I know that the key-value parser does some things with braces and spaces and it might end up removing some braces. Since the options are passed on several times to several helper commands that *could* explain it. But I would have to dig deeper to confirm that this is the issue here. Unfortunately, I don't have the time to do that at the moment. So if anyone knows why the braces go missing, feel free to answer. Otherwise I'll have a look later, but I can't promise I'll find the out why we need that many braces.

Comment: @moewe Ok, no problem. It is solved - that's the main goal :).

Comment: @moewe found the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since @moewe says he has not much time currently, and I was curious, I did some digging. Please note that I did *not* read much source code for this digging, so I'm not sure whether that's the only problem, but here is what happens in short (with *much* skipped):

1. The key-val parser strips the first pair of braces (that's intentional behaviour and usually does no harm).
2. The value of the `title` key (if used) is forwarded as the optional argument to the `\blx@head@bibliography` macro. And here lies the issue, what is done is (with `<title>` being the argument to the `title` key):

   ```latex
   \ifblank{<title>}
     {\csuse{blx@head@bibliography}}
     {\csuse{blx@head@bibliography}[<title>]}
   ```

   And the `\blx@head@bibliography` macro grabs its optional argument without checking for balanced brackets (as is done for almost all macros) by using `\@protected@testopt`, so the closing bracket in your `<title>` stops the argument grabbing of `\blx@head@bibliography` too early.

Note that this is a bug in the way `\blx@head@bibliography` is used here internally. Instead of doing

```latex
\ifblank{<title>}
  {\csuse{blx@head@bibliography}}
  {\csuse{blx@head@bibliography}[<title>]}
```

`biblatex` should have been doing

```latex
\ifblank{<title>}
  {\csuse{blx@head@bibliography}}
  {\csuse{blx@head@bibliography}[{<title>}]}
```

(note the additional braces)

Comment: Perfect! Are you planning to report the bug?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner yes I am.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner [bug reported](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/952) and [pull request opened](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/953).

Comment: The issue should be fixed in the next version of `biblatex`. (But as always I have no idea when it will be released, so for the time being, add double braces.)